# Media Response Cacheability Options

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sitecore, cdn

Context: Sitecore (7.1) website serving 25 locales, media served from CDN's (1 one from world wide, 1 provider only for china region)
On exiting china locale, two weeks ago, [website.com.cn - somehow similar domain] redirects to [website.com/cn - sitecore] so now website.com.cn = website.com/cn.

Issue has been signaled by monitoring tools for high average response time, I might add huge response time. The issue spotted by hosting engineers was the CDN response headers incorrect directive “cache-control: private”.  This instructs the CDN service to load content from the original CD servers for all web requests.

I'm not going in to details, nothing unusual in IIS logs, processor or memory on CD servers are in standard parameters all this time.

Spending more time into how response headers should be set up cacheable  for browser clients or CDN, the best set up for media response cacheability is "cache-control: public" to fix the weird long response for new locale and set up the option in correct way.

Easy change in web config:

```
<setting name="MediaResponse.Cacheability" value="public" />

<setting name="MediaResponse.CacheExtensions" value="" />

<setting name="MediaResponse.MaxAge" value="7.00:00:00" />

<setting name="MediaResponse.SlidingExpiration" value="" />
```

The problem spotted:

[image]

If **`MediaResponse.Cacheability`** value is **`true`**, **`no-cache`** directive gets by default value  **`Set-Cookie`**.

Question 1: This can mess around website security? if User1 access image via some page, logs in in website, cookies implementation. User2 access same image and `Cache-Control:public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"` is it possible to receive cookies modified by User1? or I read to much between words?

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.

Quiestion 2: How to set up correct Sitecore media response headers to get optimum performance by CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking CDN engineers about this, I did not got straight answer about, but they ensure me nothing can go wrong. My assumption were correct, cookies are stored on intermediate proxy (CDN) if `cache="Set-Cookie"` on response header.

Setting up cookies (dummy ones, not to mention login, tracking...) on media items is pure aberration so..